# Using returned data from controller in Laravel blade

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

With Laravel, I'm returning data from controller to blade. How to access to **datesValid** value in blade directly? I want to print the value in that case true.

Controller code:

```
if (empty($source)) {
   return ["recordsTotal" => 0, "recordsFiltered" => 0, 'data' => [], 'datesValid' => $datesValid];
} else {
   return ["recordsTotal" => $source['count'][0]['count'], "recordsFiltered" => $source['count'][0]['count'], 'data' => $source['result'], 'datesValid' => $datesValid ];
}
```

Comment: Hello, you are just dumping the data, you should return a view providing it with the data. you should put this array in a variable named something. like: $result and send it to the View. then look to my answer

Comment: And please take a look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views

Comment: Woud be possible to use jQuery to extract this data from controller's return?

Comment: Yes sure you can do this, but you should return the result as json, so you can use response()->json($result); and you should print it using jquery not blade

Comment: I cannot. I have to send array, as it is in controller. This is my problem.

Comment: there is no problem with that, 
this will return json object, you can parse it as json. but you should print it through html

Comment: Sorry for bothering but how to do that? Many thanks for help!

Comment: dont worry, to do that you can either add an element that should contain these result, or to generate these elements on runtime, 

its from javascript. so you can either use $('#elementId').val(result['datesValid'])... or you can do foreach to the result if it is an array and then create elements then append them to the parent element

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

please take a look on this: [laravel blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade)

if from controller you are sending it like this:

```
return view('x', ['result' => $result]);
```

and result is an object containing these data.
So you can do:

```
{{$result->datesValid}}
```

if it is an array so you can do:

```
{{$result['datesValid']}}
```